# R - Parsing all rows & columns of a Dataframe into one column

Tags: r

I am using R for reading certain values in a dataset.

I have values in a data frame all scattered in different columns & rows, some values might be NA as well.

e.g. below three columns `V1 V2 V3`, and their respective values.

```
my_data <- read.table(text="
V1      V2      V3    
NA      NA      90
abc    89.09    $50
76799   NA      NA
02:15   def     1", header=TRUE)
```

What I would like to do is parse this data frame, create a new data frame, omit all NA values. The new data frame would have one column, lets say Value column. (order of the samples coming is not an issue)

New Data Frame (Output Required):

```
Value
abc
76799
02:15
89.09
def
90
$50
1
```

Comment: `data.frame(Value=unlist(dat[!is.na(dat)]))` or something like that.

Comment: @thelatemail `unlist` is unnecessary here. Just `data.frame(Value=dat[!is.na(dat)])` works.

Comment: @N8TRO - well spotted, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks @N8TRO .Also, there can be blank values along with NA, can existing data.frame(Value=dat[!is.na(dat)]) be reused to add some conditions or again work on this new data frame?

Comment: or may be set all of the "" (blank cells) to NA before data.frame(Value=dat[!is.na(dat)])

Comment: I'm thinking R will generate NAs automatically in this scenario, but if not, you can do this: `dat[which(dat == "")]<-NA`

Comment: This really helps. BTW, I want to mark this as an answer, can I mark it it as comment as answered or if you can add one more which I can mark as answered. So that other know that this question is answered.